# How to have multiple graphs per dimension in dc.js?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

Assume the following dataset:

```
var data = [
    {
        "userId": "u1",
        "questionId": "q1",
        "answerId": "a1"
    },
    ...
];
```

I would like to plot a list of pie charts. Each pie chart corresponds to one question, with the pies being the answers of that question.

Now, when someone clicks on a pie to select an answer, it will update the remaining pie charts with the users who also selected this answer.

Basically, the use case is "users who answer "a1" to question "q1" also answered to question "q2" with the distribution given by the pies, etc.

I'm not sure what is the most optimal way to proceed.
Should I use several instances of crossfilter? Is it doable with only one? How can I implement this filter? It seems the filter applies on the user, but the dimensions are the answers...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often getting an easy answer from crossfilter means structuring your data so it is a flat array of the rows you want to count. Here you want to count users.

If this is your entire visualization, and you can restructure your data, the easiest way to get what you want will be to have a row per user:

```
[{"userId": "u1",
    "q1": "a1",
    "q2": "a2",
    ...
},
 {"userId": "u2",
    "q1": "a1",
    "q2": "a2", 
    ... 
}]
```

Now you'll get what you were asking for automatically just by having dimensions keyed on each question, each with the default `reduceCount` group.

The dimensions will be like this:

```
var dim = cf.dimension(function(d) { 
    return d.q1; 
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Actually, I'm not sure it works. After structuring the data, I create dimensions say for q1: var dim = cf.dimension(function(d) { return "q1"});, then the group: var grp = dim.group.reduceCount(); This gives me only a count of questions q1, not the separate answers... Do you know how to get a count per answer?

Comment: actually, I solved it. the dim should be like that: var dim = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d["q1"]; }); Thanks!